# Using Material Design Lite API functions in Typescript

Tags: typescript, material-design-lite

I'm trying to use the undocumented "Material Design Lite" API and I'm getting a syntax error in Visual Studio of:
"**Property MaterialCheckbox does not exist on type Element**".
Do I need a typescript definition file or something? I found a typescript definition file, but it did not help.  I don't even see any property called MaterialCheckbox in the debugger.

```
document.querySelector('#my_checkbox').MaterialCheckbox.disable();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Visual Studio doesn't understand that our component handler adds `MaterialCheckbox` to the prototype. I don't know of any way to resolve this since I'm not sure of any editor that let's you modify the existing core definitions.

Comment: Is there a workaround to use these internal MDL methods?

Comment: Just use them. Unless Typescript is preventing it somehow, in which case that isn't an MDL problem.

Comment: This line of code worked for me to get a reference to the element so I could use the API: junk = document.getElementById('myTextField1').parentNode;

Comment: Ah, so your ID wasn't on the root node but on the checkbox itself (which doesn't have the API.) This has been a confusing bit for developers since the beginning (especially since the JS API is undocumented on the site.) We're focusing on clarifying this with V2. Really sorry for the inconvenience here.